# Странный хеш при проверке на робота

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

На картинке показан стрелочкой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подсказка для роботов.

Comment: не хэш, а гуид.

Comment: @Grundy осталось их объединить и получить ...

Comment: @alexolut, нужно всего лишь ...

Comment: Хохмачи, хэид выходит :) Ну или гуш. Но отчего подсказка выходит стоило бы разобраться.

Comment: Капчу фиксят, но еще не дофиксили: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365776/captcha-what-captcha#comment572586_365776